# Slow a CABasicAnimation down whilst it is animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

Is there a way to alter the values of a repeating `CABasicAnimation` while it is animating?

So I have the following shaking animation:

```
CABasicAnimation * shake=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[shake setDuration:0.05];
[shake setRepeatCount:130];
[shake setAutoreverses:YES];
[shake setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([clock center].x-12.0f, [clock center].y)]];
[shake setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([clock center].x+12.0f, [clock center].y)]];
[shake setDelegate:self];
[[clock layer] addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];
```

I want the shaking to slow down towards the end of this animation. Im thinking this could be done if I could adjust the `duration` while the animation is repeating, but I cannot find anyway of doing this.

My second thought was to have several animations, one running after the other, with each animation having slightly longer duration than the previous one. But Im hoping there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your own `timingFunction` on the animation which allows you to specify, in detail, the full time profile of the animation. Check out the [`CAMediaTimingFunction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class.